# creat vf page automatically account will be created

Tags: visualforce, trigger, workflow, visualforce-component, webservices

I am new to salesforce.I have one requirement,i create visualforce page automatically it creates the account.Please help me.

Comment: Suggest you make an attempt yourself based on what you learn from this [Visualforce Basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals) material.

Comment: welcome to SFSE, check out [ask] for best results

Comment: If you want good answers from the community, ask a good question :) It's good to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

First to create one simple VF page Like:(Name : newAccRec)

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" label="Name"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Then go to Buttons, Links, and Actions in Account, here to edit the standard button name is New like as :[image: NewButtonEdit]

save and create new account.